# how to display data-point like 0-10,10-20..etc on xAxis in hichart

Tags: charts, highcharts, column-chart

I want to display data-point like 0-10,11-20…on xAxis. Please check following example. So please suggest me any properties or link for this in hichart

**Chart Type** : Column Chart

**Tool**: Hichart

[image]

Comment: I wand to display series in dynamic for example starting point 0 fix but last point not fix..it dependent upon max value which I have...for example........... 0-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,..........111-220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to include the category labels in the data series. For example...

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                name: '0-10',
                y: 5,
            }, {
                name: '11-20',
                y: 6,
            }, {
                name: '21-30',
                y: 2,
            }, {
                name: '31-40',
                y: 3
            }],
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to generate dynamic series..means starting point fix but end point not fix..it is dependent upon database max value

Comment: You'll need to process your data to determine what bins you want based on whatever criteria you determine. If your question is about how to process the data to determine the bins, you'll need to show us what you're doing, and ask something more specific.